# String to Int C++ (stoi)

Tags: c++, string, int

I know that this is a common question here, but I haven't found an explanation for why the below code snippet will not work. I appreciate any insight into the C++ workings.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int reverse(int x) {
    string s = to_string(x);string s2;
    for(int i = s.length(); i != -1; --i){
        s2 += s[i];
    }
    return stoi(s2);
}

int main(){
   cout <<reverse(123)<<endl;
}
```

*NOTE*: I am aware of the `reverse()` function in the `<algorithm>` library, but I can't use it for this coding challenge.

Comment: _will not work_ is not a meaningful problem. What about your code doesn't work? Does it compile, does it run, does it output anything, what are you expecting the output to be, what is the output? Please [edit] your question to include some details.

Comment: next time pls provide the error(s) you see. or describe in more detail. =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that this is C++11 (or later) and you want to reverse the value. In that case it does not work properly because `s[s.length()]` is a `\0` character.

As a result you're setting your `s2` string to the following characters: '\0', '3', '2', 1' which is interpreted as an empty string by `std::stoi` and a `std::invalid_argument` exception is thrown because no conversion can be made.

To fix this, you need to begin your iteration with `i = s.length() - 1`:

```
for (int i = s.length() - 1; i != -1; --i) {
    s2 += s[i];
}
```

Comment: Note that `s[s.length()]` is *undefined behavior* prior to C++11.

Comment: Most complete answer. Thanks, @Marcin Zawiejski.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using iterators, to avoid range confusion =)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int reverse(int x) {
    std::string s = std::to_string(x);
    std::string s2;
    auto riter = s.rbegin();
    while (riter != s.rend()) {
        s2 += *riter;
        ++riter;
    }
    return std::stoi(s2);
}

int main() {
    std::cout << reverse(123) << std::endl;
}
```

Here I used the reverse iterator. It starts at the end of a container and goes back to the start of the container.

But if you have or want to use a normal for-loop, change your code

```
for(int i = (s.length() - 1); i != -1; --i)
```

**s[s.length()]** points one past the end, which causes undefined behavior and most certainly the program to crash.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> for(int i = s.length(); i != -1; --i)
> ```

should be

```
for(int i = s.length() - 1; i != -1; --i)
```